# How can I perform OrderBy using LINQ on XML data?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have data in an XML file as follows:

```
<history>
  <history-item id="1">
     <history-url>www.google.com/ncr</history-url>
     <history-date>29/06/2017</history-date>
     <history-time>5:27:25PM</history-time>
  </history-item>
  <history-item id="2">
    <history-url>www.yahoo.com</history-url>
    <history-date>10/03/2017</history-date>
    <history-time>5:30:25PM</history-time>
  </history-item>
  <history-item id="4">
    <history-url>www.google.com/ncr</history-url>
    <history-date>23/01/2014</history-date>
    <history-time>5:27:25PM</history-time>
  </history-item>
<history>
```

My goal is to group and order this data based on `history-date`.
I am using the following code in order to achieve this:

```
    XDocument history = XDocument.Load("history.xml");
    var details =
         from c in history.Descendants("history-item")
         group c by c.Element("history-date").Value into d
         select new
         {
             Value = d.Key,
             Rows = d.Elements("history-url")
         };

    details = details.OrderBy(c => c.Value);
```

However, the problem is that - the date is only sorted by the day i.e, `dd`.

When I try to print it, the output is:

```
10/03/2017
23/01/2014
29/06/2017
```

The desired output is:

```
23/01/2014
10/03/2017
29/06/2017
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the problem is that - the date is only sorted by the day

This is because `c.Element("history-date").Value` expression produces a `string`, not a `DateTime` object. Hence, `OrderBy` puts these strings in *lexicographical* order, giving an appearance of sorting by day as long as single-digit days have zero prefixed to them.

You can fix this by parsing these strings when you get them, or right before ordering if you would rather keep them as strings in the output:

```
...
select new
 {
     Value = DateTime.ParseExact(d.Key, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
 ,   Rows = d.Elements("history-url")
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert c.value to an actual date.  as it stands it is just a string.

```
details = details.OrderBy(c => Convert.ToDateTime(c.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
details = details.OrderBy(c => DateTime.ParseExact(c.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```